# Is there a good way to display map tiles dynamic and real time?

Tags: bigdata, postgis, mapnik, cartodb, vector-tiles

**Ⅰ using python-mapnik(linux)+postgis**

I've tried using mapnik to show  big data(aboult more than 600,0000 polygon features with much points in postgis),I display it real time from python service without cache. but i meet the problem：
1.At the beginning，load table from database lost much time
2.when I zoom to 12level,map tile will loading slowly

**Ⅱ using python(flask)+postgis(MVT)+mapbox-gl**

1.display 100,0000 features(simple polygon) so fast,but display big data(aboult more than 600,0000 polygon features with much points in postgis),i find selet query need much time. it's slowly than mapnik

Now I don't know how to complete my research about displaying big vector tiles fast and realtime!!

Is there a persion like me who are interested in quickly displaying data??Any help or suggestion would be appreciated!
At last ,forgive my poor English descrption.

some information about vector tiles I've found,maybe is useful to somebody like me：

- [Vector tiles, PostGIS and OpenLayers](https://medium.com/tantotanto/vector-tiles-postgis-and-openlayers-258a3b0ce4b6)
- [An update on MVT encoders](https://carto.com/blog/inside/An-update-on-MVT-encoders/)
- [Aggregating data for faster map tiles](https://carto.com/blog/inside/An-update-on-MVT-encoders/)
- [PostGIS Performance Profiling](https://carto.com/blog/inside/postgis-performance/)
- [MVT generation: Mapnik vs PostGIS](https://carto.com/blog/inside/MVT-mapnik-vs-postgis/)
- [awesome-vector-tiles](https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles)

Comment: https://carto.com/blog/inside/An-update-on-MVT-encoders/?tdsourcetag=s_pcqq_aiomsg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to reduce as much as possible the amount of data being transferred from your database to your rendering engine.

[This blog post](https://carto.com/blog/inside/tile-aggregation/) from CARTO may give you some ideas even it's focused in point data.

For polygon datasets, in order to reduce the amount of data moved to the renderer you may want to create simplified versions to use based on the zoom level. [Mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/) is a nice tool to simplify polygons but still retain their topology. And in any case, always combine [`ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints.html) with [`ST_SnapToGrid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) to be sure you are not wasting rendering CPU with wasted pixels.

Comment: Thans for answering！ As I know，postgis provides ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology to simplify polygons,I want to calculate  tolerance according to different scale.                                 （tolerances = [6378137 * 2 * pi / (2 ** (zoom + 8)) for zoom in range(20)]） and I‘ll try it like you say. Thanks again